# R double the size of a datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following datatable:

```
DT = data.table(
   v1=as.character(rnorm(5)),
   v2=as.character(rnorm(5)),
   v3=as.character(rnorm(5)),
   v4=as.character(rnorm(5)),
   v5=as.character(rnorm(5))
)
```

and I want to double the its size by duplicating its column.

I proceed like this:

```
DT2 <- with(DT, data.table(
   v1=rep(v1,2),
   v2=rep(v2,2),
   v3=rep(v3,2),
   v4=rep(v4,2),
   v5=rep(v5,2)
)
```

Is there a faster way to iterate over the colnames?

Comment: Yes you can write `DT2 <- DT[rep(1:length(DT), 2), ]` and it will go over the rows twice!

Comment: How about `rbind`ing *DT* twice?

Comment: Hum I edit my post ... you are lucky @konvas because lengths gives the number of columns ...which is 5 in my case and I had 5 lines as well :) 
So the correct implementation is `DT2 <- DT[rep(1:nrow(DT), 2), ]`

Comment: Oh yeah obviously! I completely mistyped that..

Comment: I think it was just a typo , coming from Python I always do the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's speed you're after...

```
microbenchmark(
    rbindlist(list(DT, DT)),
    DT[rep(1:nrow(DT), 2), ],
    rbind(DT, DT)
    )
```

giving:

```
                     expr     min       lq   median        uq      max neval
  rbindlist(list(DT, DT)) 121.516 126.8520 130.9580  136.9105  353.052   100
 DT[rep(1:nrow(DT), 2), ] 784.102 814.0705 848.7600  957.3445 5709.986   100
            rbind(DT, DT) 864.976 906.2335 958.5755 1085.6325 1961.897   100
```

Comment: If the number of rows of DT is large, say 1e6 instead of 5, then rbind is just as fast as rbindlist (about 1 sec). And the DT[rep...] expression takes twice as much time as the other two (about 2 sec).